# how to check if array contains multi strings Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7, laravel-8

i have collection

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1453
  #items: array:4 [
    0 => "three"
    1 => "nine"
    2 => "one"
    3 => "two"
  ]
}
```

and this string

`'one', 'two', 'three'`

i am trying to validate if these all strings available in array

```
$array->contains('one', 'two', 'three')
```

it should return true

but everytime i am getting false

what i am doing wrong please explain thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [`Collection:diff`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_diff) in combination with [`Collection::isEmpty`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_isEmpty) for a reusable `containsAll` macro. When the supplied values contain an element that's not included in the collection to check against the result of `diff` won't be empty and therefore return false.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

Collection::macro('containsAll', function (...$values) {
    return collect($values)->diff($this)->isEmpty();
});

$collection = collect(['three', 'nine', 'one', 'two']);
$collection->containsAll('one', 'two', 'three'); // true
$collection->containsAll('one', 'five', 'three'); // false
```